# Two different actions in a form cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.4 and I want for a form two buttons each button should be have his own action but I don't know how I can redirect with submit-a  to action1 and submit-b to action2.

```
<div class="form information">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Soya', array('action' => 'reportecompravsprod')); ?>

<?php // here goes my forms  ?>

<div class="submit">
    <?php   
    echo $this->Form->submit('Vista', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'name' => 'submit-a'));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Reporte', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'name' => 'submit-b')); 
    ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you'd just use javascript on one of the buttons to change the submit url of the form, but look forward to if someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Why don't you check your submit button value in Controller and do all staff accordingly?

Comment: No because I need the same values for other view

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, there are many ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

The easiest would probably be to just make an `onClick()` on your button, and change the "action" of your form before submitting.